# Example of a (presentable $k$-linear $\infty$-)category which is dualizable but not compactly generated?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Is there an example of a presentable, stable, $k$-linear $\infty$-category which is dualizable but not compactly generated, where $k$ has characteristic zero, and which is $\text{QCoh}(X)$ (by which I mean the derived dg category of quasicoherent sheaves on $X$) for some prestack $X$?

Or, perhaps by removing some of the conditions above, e.g. being $\text{QCoh}(X)$, $k$ having characteristic zero, stability.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathrm{QCoh}(X)$? The derived ∞-category of $X$? The ∞-category of ind-pseudocoherent complexes? (I am more used to see that symbol denote the 1-category of quasicoherent sheaves)

Comment: I think this is open even if you drop the $\infty$, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5934) where they have a partial result in that direction.

Comment: @DenisNardin Yes, sorry, I mean the dg derived category of quasicoherent sheaves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $X$ is a locally compact topological space, then
$\mathrm{Shv}(X, \mathrm{Mod}_{k} )$ is a presentable $k$-linear stable $\infty$-category which is dualizable (in fact, self-dual), but is rarely compactly generated (for example, this fails for $X = \mathbf{R}$).

Comment: There’s a typo here somewhere.  I’m guessing the first “compactly generated”?

Comment: If I may, a reference for this is section 21.1.7 in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/SAG-rootfile.pdf. Also worth noting is that a stable $k$-linear $\infty$-category is dualizable if and only if it is a retract of a compactly generated one (Theorem D.7.0.7 in op. cit.).